# Maximize function with two parameters

Tags: python, python-2.7, scipy, minimize

I'm trying to find the values of two parameters called **a** e **b** that maximize a function f(x,a,b), with b>0.
I wrote this:

```
a=0.1 #start value for a
b=150 #start value for b
n=len(x)
def f(y,a,b):
    c=sum([np.log(1-a/b*i) for i in y])
    return -n*np.log(b)+(1-a/a)*c
minimize(f,x,args=(a,b))
```

where x is an array with my data.

I get the following error:

```
RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in log
  c=sum([np.log(1-a/b*i) for i in x])
C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\_methods.py:26: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in reduce
  return umr_maximum(a, axis, None, out, keepdims)
      fun: nan
 hess_inv: array([[1, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 1, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 1, ..., 0, 0, 0],
       ...,
       [0, 0, 0, ..., 1, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 1, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 1]])
      jac: array([nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan,
       nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan,
       nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan,
       nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan,
       nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan,
       nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan,
       nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan,
       nan, nan, nan, nan])
  message: 'Desired error not necessarily achieved due to precision loss.'
     nfev: 97
      nit: 0
     njev: 1
   status: 2
  success: False
```

Could someone help me?

Comment: Could you show us the `y` array ?

Answer (score 1):

For this problem, since you are searching for optimal values of `a`, `b` your objective should be redefined as follows,

```
def f(x,y):
    a = x[0] # Parameter 1
    b = x[1] # Parameter 2
    c=sum([np.log(1-a/b*i) for i in y])
    return -n*np.log(b)+(1-a/a)*c
minimize(f,x,args=(y))
```

Next, you have to implement a check to ensure that `np.log` gets a `value > 0.0` else you would get a domain error. You can compute the bounds of the value of `a` w.r.t `b` or the other way around and then specify `bounds`.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting boundarys with the `bounds` property of [`minimize()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.minimize.html). Probably your b gets negative at one point.